# write xml file c# asp.net, and control file size

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I create an xml file and write some information in it. 
When i do this operation, i follow these steps:

1. I get data from db and map it my object list;
2. In the foreach iteration statement write the xml file.

But my data size changable.

My problem is my xml file size must not exceed 200 mb. If my data exceeds 200 mb. I have to divide into two parts, if exceeds 400 mb divide into three parts.

Can I control the data size before filling the xml file?

For example if my list object data size exceeds 200 mb, I will divide my list object into two parts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you write xml method, but you can try something like this.
Main idea is count length of each record in list

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MyData
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = string.Format("xmlFile_{0}.xml", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.mm.ss"));
        int dataLength = 0;
        int limit = 100500;

        List<MyData> list = new List<MyData>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        { 
            Random r = new Random();
            string preparedData = Convert.ToBase64String( 
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(r.Next(int.MaxValue).ToString())
                );

            MyData mydata = new MyData { id = i, data = preparedData };

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, mydata);
            string xmlResult = stringWriter.ToString();
            dataLength += xmlResult.Length;
            if (dataLength <= limit)
                // insert you write method here
                File.AppendAllText(fileName, xmlResult);
            else
            { 
                // create new file or something else you want
            }

            list.Add(mydata);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```